# Fetching data from firebase database: it appears to toast only but not saved in Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I'm developing an app to fetch contacts to my app as I implemented it, I'm receiving it to toast all contacts, but contacts are not going in Firebase Database. I tried a lot, but still it can not be stored in firebase. To check it, I tried to get to toast, and its getting all list, but not storing.
Following is the code

```
public ProgressDialog dialog;
public DatabaseReference db; 




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("contact-fetch-firebase");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setMessage("Uploading contacts...");


    Cursor contacts = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,new String[]{
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
            },
            null,
            null,
            null
    );


    HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();

    if(contacts!=null) {
        while(contacts.moveToNext()){
            map.put(
                    contacts.getString(contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)),
                    contacts.getString(contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))
            );
        }
        contacts.close();
    }

    dialog.show();


    Iterator i = map.keySet().iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        String key=(String)i.next();
        Object value=(Object) map.get(key);



                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Name: " + key + " Contact Number: " + value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


    db.updateChildren(map)

            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    String key = db.child("user").push().getKey();
                    String value = db.child("key").push().getKey();

                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Contacts uploaded successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })

            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Log.w("MKN","Error: "+e.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Contacts upload failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });


        }


    }
```

Comment: Is "Contacts uploaded successfully!" toast showing?

Comment: Is "Contacts uploaded successfully!" toast showing? -- NO

Comment: so is it showing fail?

Comment: Yes it's showing  "Contacts upload failed" Toast

Comment: did you check what exception  is throwing in failure ??

Comment: @Yash: reposting your question won't help, unless you provide the minimum information on what's going wrong. If you have additional information (such as the error message from the exception), edit your original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way -

```
Iterator i = map.keySet().iterator();
while(i.hasNext()) {
    String key=(String)i.next();
    Object value=(Object) map.get(key);

     db.updateChildren(map)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                String key = db.child("user").push().getKey();
                String value = db.child("key").push().getKey();

                dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Contacts uploaded successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })

        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.w("MKN","Error: "+e.getException());
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: It's showing Uploading Contacts and after  Loading from so long &  in firebase console its showing structure contact-fetch-firebase - users  user:  - 'user '

Comment: What does this Log prints - Log.w("MKN","Error: "+e.getException()); (In onFailure( ) method).

Comment: Don't know exactly i used it from stackoverflow post somewhere

Comment: @Yash How do you not know what `Log.w` does? It basically logs a warning to the logcat of your device. This can be read by clicking on the "Logcat" tab at the bottom of Android Studio. (P.S. Consider reading the code and/or the documentation to see what a particular function does.)

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost thing to consider is to change the authentication rules of your database,

The below rules allow authenticated users only to read or write data.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Below rules will allow everyone to read & write data without authentication.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Comment: i have already change it to make it apply changes in it  {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}

Comment: Try checking all the steps given in the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write